# different progressColor for LinearPercentIndicator in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, indicator

I got 3 different values ; $finalD, $finalA, $finalS

therefore, I got 3 different linearPercentIndicator ;

```
//linear1
new Text(" $finalD "),
LinearPercentIndicator(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50,
            animation: true,
            lineHeight: 25.0,
            animationDuration: 2500,
            percent: percentage,
            center: Text(message),
            linearStrokeCap: LinearStrokeCap.roundAll,
            progressColor: currentProgressColor(),
          ),

//linear2
new Text(" $finalA "),
LinearPercentIndicator(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50,
            animation: true,
            lineHeight: 25.0,
            animationDuration: 2500,
            percent: percentage1,
            center: Text(message1),
            linearStrokeCap: LinearStrokeCap.roundAll,
            progressColor: currentProgressColor(),
          ),

//linear3
    new Text(" $finalS "),
    LinearPercentIndicator(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50,
                animation: true,
                lineHeight: 25.0,
                animationDuration: 2500,
                percent: percentage,
                center: Text(message),
                linearStrokeCap: LinearStrokeCap.roundAll,
                progressColor: currentProgressColor(),
              ),

          LinearPercentIndicator(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50,
            animation: true,
            lineHeight: 25.0,
            animationDuration: 2500,
            percent: percentage3,
            center: Text(message3),
            linearStrokeCap: LinearStrokeCap.roundAll,
            progressColor: currentProgressColor(),
          ),
```

to differentiate the colors, Im using **currentProgressColor()** for those **$finalD, $finalA, $finalS**

```
currentProgressColor(){
//for $finalD
     if (finalD < 10) {
       return Colors.green;
     }else if(finalD < 14) {
       return Colors.yellow;
     }else if(finalD < 21){
       return Colors.orange;
     }else if(finalD < 28){
       return Colors.deepOrangeAccent;
     }else{
       return Colors.red;
     }

//for &finalA
     else if(finalA < 8){
       return Colors.green;
     }else if(finalA < 10) {
       return Colors.yellow;
     }else if(finalA < 15){
       return Colors.orange;
     }else if(finalA < 20){
       return Colors.deepOrangeAccent;
     }else if(finalA > 19){
       return Colors.red;
     }

//for &finalS
     else if(finalS < 15){
       return Colors.green;
     }else if(finalS < 19) {
       return Colors.yellow;
     }else if(finalS < 26){
       return Colors.orange;
     }else if(finalS < 34){
       return Colors.deepOrangeAccent;
     }else{
       return Colors.red;
     }
}
```

but it only shows for the first ($finalD), others just follow and not changing to color it should be.

How should I arrange them? or is there any other way for me to differentiate the values with different colors? :)

Comment: Using the switch might work.

Answer (score 1):

The logic of your method currentProgressColor() doesn't let you go beyond the else statement `else{ return Colors.red; }` everything after that is dead code, that's why finalS and finalA will have the same value as finalD. The best solution is to have different methods because it's hard to tell this way when you want to return a value based on what finalD/A/S (the method doesn't know what value you want to use)

```
currentProgressColorD(){
//for $finalD
  if (finalD < 10) return Colors.green;
  else if(finalD < 14) return Colors.yellow;
  else if(finalD < 21) return Colors.orange;
  else if(finalD < 28) return Colors.deepOrangeAccent;
  return Colors.red; //no need of else because it will run this line at the end if the other conditions aren't true
}

currentProgressColorA(){
//for $finalA
  if (finalA < 8) return Colors.green;
  else if(finalA < 10) return Colors.yellow;
  else if(finalA < 15) return Colors.orange;
  else if(finalA < 20) return Colors.deepOrangeAccent;
  return Colors.red; //no need of else because it will run this line at the end if the other conditions aren't true
}

currentProgressColorS(){
//for $finalS
  if (finalS < 15) return Colors.green;
  else if(finalS < 19) return Colors.yellow;
  else if(finalS < 26) return Colors.orange;
  else if(finalS < 34) return Colors.deepOrangeAccent;
  return Colors.red; //no need of else because it will run this line at the end if the other conditions aren't true
}
```